# merge multiple videos to a single .mp4

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using fluent-ffmpeg in nodejs to merge multiple videos in one single file but while executing I am getting an Error: cannot find ffprobe

```
var fluent_ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

var mergedVideo = fluent_ffmpeg();
var videoNames = ['./Aleris.mp4', './Jagdamba.mp4'];

videoNames.forEach(function(videoName){
    mergedVideo = mergedVideo.addInput(videoName);
});

mergedVideo.mergeToFile('./mergedVideo.mp4', './tmp/')
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Finished!');
});
```

C:\Users\user\Desktop\FFmpeg_test3>node app.js

Error Cannot find ffprobe

Comment: Do you have `ffmpeg` installed in the system?. `fluent-ffmpeg` has direct dependency on it.

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981140/cannot-find-ffprobe