# I want to auto generate video subtitle using npm package ffmpeg-fluent in node js while viideo uploaded from react front-end side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have node js application in that  have build REST APIs. I want video module in front-end side(React js) where user upload any video (not youtube) and from backend side (node js) I want to automatically generate subtitle file using ffmpeg npm package. I don't how to do that please anyone can know then guide me.

Comment: I believe this will help with installing fluent-FFmpeg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981140/cannot-find-ffprobe

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AI to generate subtitles you can't just use FFMpeg. Look up https://github.com/openai/whisper , I am also building an open source project around Whisper which I'll release soon.